# Cat doesn't locate and combine files that are present

Tags: bash, shell, cat

### Issue

I've been trying to use cat to combine up a bunch of files based on part of the name within my files but can't seem to get it to work.

If I run `cat client1* > test.tsv` it creates the file without issue (tested by adding some text to the file) but using the below loops create errors that don't make sense as the files are present. I've checked online and burnt a whole in my screen staring at my code but I don't understand what I've done wrong.

Below is a basic example I've set up that I hope someone might be able to clarify for me:

### Code

```
touch client1.tsv client2.tsv client3.tsv client4.tsv  client5.tsv client6.tsv

for f in $(find*.tsv); do cp $f title-$f; done

for HEADER in $(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "title-*.tsv" -printf "%f\n"); do ACCOUNT=$(echo $HEADER | sed -Ee "s/^title-//" -e "s/.tsv$//");  cat "$ACCOUNT*.tsv" > "data-$ACCOUNT.tsv"; done
```

### output

```
cat: 'client4*.tsv': No such file or directory
cat: 'client5*.tsv': No such file or directory
cat: 'client6*.tsv': No such file or directory
cat: 'client1*.tsv': No such file or directory
cat: 'client2*.tsv': No such file or directory
cat: 'client3*.tsv': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Asterisk (`*`) loses its special meaning between double quotes, you need to move it outside, e.g `"$ACCOUNT"*.tsv`. If you run into another error after fixing that (which is very likely), edit your question and we'll reopen it.

Comment: @oguzismail yep, it smashed it... and I am ashamed with myself that this has never come up for me before in any of the scripts I've written. Guess maybe I got lucky XD